# Binding XAML to custom entry in xamarin.form.behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

I have a custom entry in my code, but I wish to use the `xamarin.form.behavior` property.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/behaviors/

My final target is like, type `Behavior = NameValidation`or `Behavior = IdentityValidation` in XAML, then it will go find the different validation which already inherited from `Behavior` class.

How should I explore hidden property inside the custom entry and achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly declare you custom entry class:

```
public class YourCustomEntry : Entry
{
    public YourCustomEntry()
    {
    }

    public string YourCustomField { get; set; }

    // You could also create a BindableProperty: http://xamandor.me/2015/02/27/custom-controls-with-xamarin-forms/
}
```

Then create a custom behavior:

```
public class NumericValidationBehavior : Behavior<YourCustomEntry>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(YourCustomEntry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(YourCustomEntry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Do something with you custom property
        ((YourCustomEntry)sender).YourCustomField = "test";
    }
}
```